# how do i move an image at the background when there is a transparent image at the foreground?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, move

im making a website where there will be two image the foreground and the background. the background can be changeable by uploading images and the foreground stays the same but how how can i drag and re-size the background image without doing anything to the foreground image?

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}


#shirt {
    margin-top: 130px;
}

#image_overlay {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 10; 
    width: 1000px;
    height: 900px;
}

#bg_img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    left: 25px;
    right: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-right: -100px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 550px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    
}

#fg_img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-filter: saturate(8);
}



/*aside*/
.click_shirt{
    position: relative;
}
.one{
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 52px;
    top: -2px;
    position: absolute;
}
.one ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.one ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    
}
.one img{
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
}

.image_upload{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1000px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device, intial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

    <title>Codezard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  </style>
     
</head>

<body>
   <div id="middle_content" class="span7">
                <div id="print" class="print">
                    <div id="image_overlay">
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_GET["img"]))
                            {
                                $n=$_GET["img"];
                                echo "<img id='bg_img' src='photos/".$n."'>";
                            }
                        ?>
                       <img id="fg_img" src="http://dumpfm.s3.amazonaws.com/images/20130320/1363836943140-dumpfm-FAUXreal-black-hole-haiku-transparent-invert.png"> 
                        <form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="image_upload">
                            <input type="file" name="file"><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                
                
            </div>   
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```